# First hover goes without any animations

Tags: jquery, animation, hover

When I move the mouse over the div.box the div.title animates up. This is correct. The problem is that at the very first hover it goes to the top without any animations. After the first hover everyting works fine.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>

<style>
    .box { width: 30%; height: 300px; float: left; background: #ccc; position: relative; overflow: hidden; margin-right: 20px; }
    .title { height: 300px; width: 100%; background: #333; position: absolute; bottom: -260px; }
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".box").hover(function(){
            $(this).find(".title").animate({top:'0px'},300);
        }, function() {
            $(this).find(".title").animate({top:'260px'},300);
        }); 
    });
</script>

<div class="box">
    <div class="title"></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <div class="title"></div>
</div>
```

Can anyone see what I have done wrong?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4gnrrgn/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set initial top value for title div. Change the css as follows

```
.title { 
  height: 300px; 
  width: 100%; 
  background: #333; 
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: -260px;
  top: 260px;
}
```

Comment: Aha...so simple! Thanks Thangaraja!